# How can I display a range of values in a rails select option while still selecting only one of the options?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've currently got a select statement that looks like so:

```
<%= f.select :assessmentYear, (Time.now.year-1..Time.now.year+1).to_a, :prompt=>true  %>
```

I need it to show a range in the selection, though. Such as, 2012-2013, 2013-2014, etc.
But it should still save the same value as it is now (eg, 2012-2013 would save 2012, 2013-2014 would save 2013, etc).

This is a request by a user- my application is for an academic institute, and because the academic year is split up amongst two calendar years, it can be confusing when referring to a single value.

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a helper that returns an array like `[['year-year+1', 'year'], ...]`. Something similar to:

```
def academic_years 
  years = Array.new
  (Time.now.year-1..Time.now.year+1).each do |year|
     years << ["#{year}-#{year+1}", year]
  end
  return years
end
```

and then call the helper like

```
<%= f.select :assessmentYear, options_for_select( academic_years ), :prompt=>true  %>
```

The helper `options_for_select` will generate something like:

```
<option value="2012">2012-2013</option>
<option value="2013">2013-2014</option>
...
```